# Is there any simple way to add a prefix to each element of an array in C?

Tags: c, prefix, gray-code

I'm solving gray code problem. 
I made my logic using recursive call.
Everything look ok but I have no idea how to prefix '0' or '1' to each element of an array.
eg) prefix 0 : { 00, 01, 11, 10 } -> { 000, 001, 011, 010 } or 
    prefix 1 : { 00, 01, 11, 10 } -> { 100, 101, 111, 110 }

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

int grayCode(int list[], int bit)
{
    int listLen = strlen(list); // calculate received array length
    int revList[] = { 0 };
    int newList[] = { 0 };

    if (listLen < pow(2, bit)) // If the received array length is below 2^bit, proceed below.

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listLen; i++) // create a reverse order array
        {
            revList[i] = list[listLen - i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listLen; i++) // prefix 0 to each element of an received array, I know this doesn't work. How should I do it??
        {
            list[i] = "0" + list[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listLen; i++) // prefix 1 to each element of an reverse array, I know this doesn't work. How should I do it??
        {
            revList[i] = "1" + revList[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listLen; i++)  // put all elements of received array in the new array
        {
            newList[i] = list[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listLen; i++)  // put all elements of reverse array in the new array
        {
            newList[listLen + i] = revList[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listLen * 2; i++)  // print all elements in a new array
        {
            printf("%d bit Gray Code is { ", bit);
            printf("%d, ", newList[i]); 
            printf("}\n");
        }

        grayCode(newList, bit); // Recursive call
    }

    else if (listLen == pow(2, bit)) // If the received array length is same as 2^bit, return.
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int initList[2] = { 0, 1 };
    int bit;

    printf("Which bit of gray-code do you want? : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &bit);

    while (bit < 1)
    {
        printf("Input an integer bigger than 1 : ");
        scanf_s("%d", &bit);
    }

    if (bit == 1)
    {
        printf("1 bit Gray Code is { 0, 1 }\n");
    }

    else if (bit > 1)
    {
        grayCode(initList, bit);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use a string function (`strlen`) on something not a string (`list` is a pointer to `int`)? That's not usually a good idea, as `strlen` will stop at the first zero *byte* (and an `int` is usually four bytes).

Comment: You dont seem to be allocating space for your lists

Comment: There are also quite a few other problems and cases of [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code.

Comment: Please fix the indention by editing your post.

Comment: Are these strings or integers? Adding a 0 to the front of an integer is meaningless. If you wanted to display your integers with a leading 0 this can be done using printf formatting.

Comment: are these Integers meant to be binary values?

Comment: @Lundin Sorry for ugly  indention this is my first attempt to ask a question here.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Thank you, then I think I should change it to sizeof(list)/sizeof(int) - 1, am I right?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, Thank you but would you please be more specific? I am just a novice..

Comment: @AnthonyLambert, yes! this is binary numbers so I still need to prefix 0 to elements. Just printing is not enough.

Comment: Note that pow() is a floating point function returning a double.  It should probably be avoided in this context.  2^n where n is an integer  is trivially calculated by `1<<n` so prefer `if (listLen < (1<<bit) )` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't append `0` as prefix to an integer.
An integer starting with `0` is assumed as octal representation of corresponding decimal integer, *i.e.*:

> (037)<sub>8</sub> == (31)<sub>10</sub>

If you really want to save the numbers with prefixed `0`s, you will have to store the numbers as strings.

You can use a temporary string for storing intermediates.

The algorithm will be:

```
char str[10] = "01";      // To be converted to 001
char temp[10];

strcpy(temp, "0");     // temp = "0", str = "01"
strcat(temp, str);     // temp = "001", str = "01"
strcpy(str, temp);     // temp = "001", str = "001"
```

Comment: Wow, I couldn't think about using type 'char'! Thank you very much!!